# C++ templates, method prototypes and implementation

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following in a header .h++ file:

```
template<typename N, 
         typename V = int, 
         typename C = std::less<N>, 
         typename A = std::allocator<N>>
class my_class {
  public:
    ...
  private:
    N* buy_node_( const V& );
    ...
};
```

In the implementation .c++ file i have

```
template <typename N, typename V, typename C, typename A>
typename my_class<N, V, C, A>::N* 
my_class<N, V, C, A>::buy_node_( const V& v )
{
  ...
}
```

But this gives me the error :

```
error: prototype for ... does not match any in class ...
```

However, if i do this instead, in the header:

```
template<typename N, 
         typename V = int, 
         typename C = std::less<N>, 
         typename A = std::allocator<N>>
class my_class {
  public:
    ...
  private:
    typedef N node_t;
    N* buy_node_( const V& );
    ...
};
```

and this in the implementation:

```
template <typename N, typename V, typename C, typename A>
typename my_class<N, V, C, A>::node_t* 
my_class<N, V, C, A>::buy_node_( const V& v )
{
  ...
}
```

it compiles fine. Im curious as to why i need the typedef?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
typename my_class<N, V, C, A>::N*
```

is trying to refer to a typedef in `my_class`, but `my_class` does not define such a typedef. The `typename` keyword in this case is used to say "this is a typedef" (e.g. `typedef T::value`).

The second version works as `node_t` is a typedef and `node_t` and `N` are equivalent.

As `N` is part of the template, you can simply say:

```
N*
```

Comment: What `typedef` operates with values? And `N` can be not only `typedef` but also simple nested class.